# Building an iPhone application reports 'An executable was signed with invalid entitlements'

Tags: iphone, executable, code-signing, entitlements

I'm trying to install my iPhone application on my device for testing and whenever I try to build it I get:

> The executable was signed with invalid entitlements
>
> The entitlements specificed in your
>   application's Code Signing
>   Entitlements do not match those
>   specified in your provisioning
>   profile.

Now I've tried adding an `Entitlements.plist` file and both checking and unchecking get-task-allow. I've added the file name under *Code Signing Entitlements* under the project and then under the target, both, neither, etc. I've deleted and re-created every application id, provisioning profile, and certificate. Those all seem valid. This is not an ad-hoc distribution (it's development) and it's not a jailbroken phone.

Where in the provisioning profile are any Code Signing Entitlements specified?

Comment: I posted an answet that worked for me here, check it to see if it works for you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333034/im-still-getting-the-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-erro

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by copying my project to a different spot, creating a new project and then re-copying the previous project files into the new project.

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the steps given in the Apple provisioning portal properly to make my application working on iPhone. I also rebooted my machine, and created a new project to test. It was not working for me. I was getting the same error every time.

Then I re-installed [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode). Then it worked for me. I successfully ran my application
on my iPhone...