# i'm still getting the "The executable was signed with invalid entitlements." error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I followed your steps and added the Entitlements.plist file to my project. I also added the get-task-allow field and set it to a boolean and unchecked the box. I go to build my application and I still get the error:

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile.

(0xE8008016).

can anyone help me out?

thanks

Comment: what steps are you talking about?

Comment: I have the same problem. I can get my provisioning profile to work on my jailbroken iPad and iPod touch 4G, but not on my unjailbroken iPhone 3g and iPhone 4.

Comment: oops..here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `Entitlements.plist` from your project and then try cleaning and building your project.

It is because the distribution provisioning profile which you might have added to code signing has invalidated or expired.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to remove Entitlements from Code Signing section of the Build Settings for the target (using XCode 4.2)

Answer (score 0):

After installing xCode 4 I had this problem this morning with an iPhone running 4.2.1 that I had last worked with well before I did the xCode upgrade.

After fumbling a bit I got the error to go away by clicking the refresh button for the device in the Organizer - Devices.

Go to Devices in the Organizer, then select Provisioning Profiles, then select the device and click the Device Provisioning Refresh button at the bottom of the page.

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even if you add Entitlements.plist file you could receive the same error message.

Get your device's **unique id** number. Then open the provisioning file that you created for your project in **Text Edit** and check for your device Id in it. If it is not found, then this could be one problem for receiving the error message.

Answer (score 0):

When you submitted to AppStore, you changed Code Signing values, so now if you want to continue developing, you have to change them back.

The following steps fixed it for me:
- Click on your project name under PROJECT (just above TARGETS)
- Select the tab Build Settings
- In the section Code Signing change the values for Debug and for Release to be "iPhone Developer" instead of "iPhone Distribution"

Answer (score 0):

I have exact error when I open a project written on different machine with different profile.

So here is how I fix it: Assume that my profile is **DevelopmentProfile.mobileprovision**, I copy that file to a directory, and run this command:

`security cms -D -i DevelopmentProfile.mobileprovision |  grep -A12 "Entitlements"`

Then I copy the output XML and paste it in a file called **Entitlements.plist**, put it under the project's directory.

Then in Build Settings/Code Signing, you can select the signing identity correspondent to the DevelopmentProfile.mobileprovision.

This should solve the problem.