# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing, signing, code-signing-entitlements

So here we are yet again. I already have an app on the app store, that took me 2 days to get past all the errors and just get the thing on there.

Right now, I'm trying to put the 1.1 update on my brother's iPod Touch for testing. I pressed 'Use for development'. That's fine, works. Then i build and go, and it says 'The iPod “Dans Ipod touch” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with which the application was signed.' so i press Install And Run to install the provisioning profile, and then get 'The executable was signed with invalid entitlements'.

I'll be clear - all i want to do right now is to test the app on an iPod Touch, which is plugged into the computer. How do I get past this error and do that? I have what i thought was a valid provisioning profile selected in active target and active executable, but apparently that isn't enough. Any ideas?

Comment: I posted an answet that worked for me here, check it to see if it works for you too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5333034/im-still-getting-the-the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements-erro

Comment: possible duplicate of [The executable was signed with invalid entitlements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074546/the-executable-was-signed-with-invalid-entitlements)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of easy things to try:

- Do a Clean before building again.
- Go to Xcode's Organizer and click on all the Profiles, checking they are valid. Xcode'll throw up warning text if say, something is missing in Keychain.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your profile contains your iPod device UDID. Make sure that the certificate with which the profile is signed is installed in your keychain. Also make sure the bundle id in your profile and app info.plist match.

Answer (score 1):

Outdated provisioning profiles can often be a problem. Click on your Project and your Target and then individually check the provisioning profile for each code signing identity  (Ad Hoc, Debug, Release etc.) by actually clicking on it. Note that it might look like the right profile, but when you click on it, it appears at the bottom of the list in 'others'. This usually means XCode is referring to an older profile. Make sure you now select the current, up-to-date profile from the list above. It is best to check ever Code Signing Identity individually just to make sure.

Once done, I recommend cleaning the project and deleting the app from your device before running it again.

Also, check your profile in Organiser and make sure it has a Green Tick (Valid Profile) and in the Provisioning Portal to ensure the required device is included in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Window -> Organizer -> Devices 
and then go to the connected device's Provisioning Profiles tab.

Note the name of the currently valid profile (must have a green tick icon).

Click the project then go to Project -> Build Settings -> Code Signing
Then copy the appropriate profile name into the Code Signing Identity field.

Clean the project

Then run the program on the device

Answer (score 0):

In one case, to solve this issue, I also had to add the provisioning profile on the iphone's provisioning profiles, available only on this phone, from Organizer>Devices. It is strange, because this device is the only one that require that action. (Anyway I'm Newbie)